# popUp без jQuery на чистом JavaScript+CSS

Tags: javascript, css

У кого есть возможность кинуть ссылку на пример popUp окна без применения Framework-ов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класс самый простой для окна

```
function ModalWindow(fadeInBox, closeBtn, callback) {
var darkLayer = document.createElement('div');
darkLayer.id = 'fade';
document.body.appendChild(darkLayer);

function init() {
    fadeInBox.style.display = 'block';

    if(callback) callback();

    darkLayer.onclick = function() {
        removeDarkLoyer();
        fadeInBox.style.display = 'none';
        return false;
    }

    if (closeBtn) {
        closeBtn.onclick = function() {
            removeDarkLoyer();
            fadeInBox.style.display = 'none';
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function removeDarkLoyer() {
    darkLayer.parentNode.removeChild(darkLayer);
}

init();
}
```

CSS для подложки

```
#fade {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:100;
    background:#000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос, возможно слегка странный, но почему в функциях return false; а не true например??

Comment: У меня тот же вопрос к @markupeк :)

Comment: `return false;` предотвращает выполнение браузером действий по умолчанию при клику на ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Я сейчас создаю свой API: [`WebWinAPI`](http://webwinapi.16mb.com/) (начал разрабатывать потом приостановил работу учу PHP чтоб потом вообще cool сделать)
А вообще это легко если умеешь "общаться" с `JavaScript, DOM` и `BOM`

Comment: Если по ссылке твоя работа, то ты крут :). А вообще по изобилию ответов, я уже понял что нужно сидеть и самому подымать вопрос, поскольку большинство уже привыкли использовать всеобщее достояние библиотек.

Comment: А BOM-то тут причем? PS: [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)

Comment: @karmadro4 BOM это например screen location

Comment: @Rules, а я думал, что это марклар... ;-) 

> BOM это например screen location

Поясните, совершенно не понимаю связи аббревиатуры и контекста.

Comment: Я имею ввиду window.screen и window.location и window.history это обьекты BOM (Browser Object Model)